# domain: @"com.facebook.sdk" - code 5 error using PFFacebookUtils

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve Facebook user friend list using this code:

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
    }
}];
```

The login as Facebook user has been implemented using parse "PFFacebookUtils"
From this tutorial https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views

and here exactly what I've  done:
1. configured my .plist file.
2. In the AppDelegate.m I've added these methods:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[Parse setApplicationId:@"your_application_id" clientKey:@"your_client_key"];
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];

}


// Facebook oauth callback
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
return [PFFacebookUtils handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [PFFacebookUtils handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Handle an interruption during the authorization flow, such as the user clicking the home button.
   [FBAppEvents activateApp];
   [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

3.In the logInViewController.m:

```
logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsLogInButton |        PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten;
    logInViewController.facebookPermissions = @[ @"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends"];
```

I can Login successfully, but when I retrieve the user friend I get this error: (Note: I'm using test users and created a friend list for them)

[image]

Please I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What versions of the Parse and Facebook SDK are you using?

Comment: Facebook SDK version is 3.9.0, Parse 1.2.15.

Comment: Then first upgrade to the latest version of both frameworks, just to rule out that there are no bugs in the older versions that might cause this. The Parse iOS SDK is at v1.7.4 as of writing this and the Facebook SDK is at 4.2.0